# Android ListView cannot be clicked after removed from a ViewGroup and added back?

Tags: android, listview, viewgroup, onitemclicklistener

I have a view A, and there's a ListView in A.

At first, I added A into a ViewGroup, and everything works fine. Items in the ListView can be clicked, and it responds correctly.

But when I remove A from the ViewGroup and add another view B into it, and later remove B and add A back into the ViewGroup, strange things happens: 
items in the ListView cann't be clicked. All the buttons in view A works fine, and the ListView can be scrolled up and down, only the items cann't be clicked. And if I refresh the ListView, or scroll it by more than a screen, the items can be clicked again. It seems as long as the items are re-generated, it works again. Does anyone know the reason?

As I did more test on different devices, it seems this only happens on Android 4.0.x(in my test it's 4.0.4). Android 2.x and 4.1.x don't seem to have this problem.

Comment: have u use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();for refresh ListView?

Answer (score 0):

After you have re-added the listView, try notifying the adapter once so that it can be refreshed using:

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried this, but it still doesn't work. Another strange thing is this happens quite randomly. Sometimes after all these steps, it still works fine, or works after a few seconds, but the possibility is low, in most cases it won't work.

Comment: And when I scroll the list down, it needs to be a little more than one screen, at some point, all the items will be clickable again together.